# register receiver in a service

Tags: android

I have a `service` that can be started and stopped from a `button`.

But within the `service` I want to register a reciever to listen for SMS broadcasts. I only want the `service` to listen for SMS while it is running. I tried `registerReceiver(receiver, intentfilter)` but this does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This question will be more helpful to people if you specify the problem. "This does not work" = "The receiver never gets called", for example? Or it gets called, but not with the SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION? Or there's an error? or ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must set permissions in the AndroidManifest file.

```
    <receiver android:name=".MySMSReciever"> 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name=
                "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

Comment: I have done that. I get an AccountManagerService and ContactsProvider error/

Comment: Is my IntentFilter correct?                                                  private static final String SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION =
        "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"  ?

Comment: Yes that is how you add the receiver in the manifest but I want to register it dynamically. The method above listens for all incoming SMS, even when my service is stopped. I want to only listen for SMS while my service is running.

Answer (score 93):

If you want to only receive the broadcast while your service is running you will need to dynamically register your receiver in onCreate()

Also it is important to not forget to unregister your receiver in the onDestroy() method!

Example:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class YourClass extends Service {

    private static final String ACTION="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    private BroadcastReceiver yourReceiver;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        final IntentFilter theFilter = new IntentFilter();
        theFilter.addAction(ACTION);
        this.yourReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // Do whatever you need it to do when it receives the broadcast
                // Example show a Toast message...
                showSuccessfulBroadcast();
            }
        };
        // Registers the receiver so that your service will listen for
        // broadcasts
        this.registerReceiver(this.yourReceiver, theFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Do not forget to unregister the receiver!!!
        this.unregisterReceiver(this.yourReceiver);
    }

    private void showSuccessfulBroadcast() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Broadcast Successful!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks DDoSAttack, this was quite easy and I spent few hours searching for this but didn't found any good solution but your was quite easy and understandable. (Y) Thanks :)

Comment: This answer is the correct one. I used this for IntentService and it also worked, and i want to put some emphasis on registering the receiver in onCreate() specifically!

Comment: It seems that the android lifecycle somehow unregisters the broadcastreceiver automatically sometimes. I was registering the receiver in onCreate, then unregister in onDestroy and I get an illegalargumentexception saying the receiver was not registered before. This is a lie. I see clearly in the logs that the service instance is the same both for register and unregister. I trigger this behaviour by finishing an activity with a  service connection to this service

Answer (score 1):

Remove the intent-filter from the xml and do only the dynamic registration of the Receiver.
If you do not want it working when the service is off, then unregister it before stopping the service. Do not forget to add the permission to the xml though....