# Activity killed by system when idle

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-activity, kill

I am writing a Location service programming that when the user go outside a predefined zone, the App will create a Notification at task bar. I am suffering from the system killing my App Activity automatically.
After I hide the App by pressing Home button, the App Activity killed by system automatically after an hour. The problem is the user cannot get any notification after the Activity killed by system.
Note: My GPS code is in the Activity Class without creating a Thread for it.

Is it possible to solve the problem by using Service? Is it possible that the Service killed by system also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, create a service, put your code there, make sure it's not too expensive (battery hog etc.) and that should do the job AndroidBegginer - i like the username good one

Comment: LOL, thanks serkan. I am writing my first Android App. I hope the system won't kill my Service automcatically

Answer (score 1):

> I am suffering from the system killing my App Activity automatically. After I hide the App by pressing Home button, the App Activity killed by system automatically after an hour.

Of course. This is normal behavior. Android is reclaiming that RAM to be able to run something else. This is no different than a browser app freeing memory associated with Web pages that it downloaded an hour ago, to have more memory for downloading future pages.

> Is it possible to solve the problem by using Service?

Yes, a service can run independently of an activity.

> Is it possible that the Service killed by system also?

Yes, Android will kill off your service after some period of time. More importantly, the *user* will kill off your service after some period of time, either via a task killer or the Manage Services screen in the Settings app. Your service needs to die, because if it does not, the user's entire phone will die, because it will run out of battery life. GPS is a significant battery drain -- the phone will only be able to run for a handful of hours before it runs out of charge.

> I am writing a Location service programming that when the user go outside a predefined zone, the App will create a Notification at task bar.

This is very possible to write. It is somewhat difficult to write well, in ways that will provide this functionality while not causing excessive battery drain.

Comment: One more question. In my case, will the OS call onDestroy method when it kills Activity or Service?

Comment: @Android Beginner: `onDestroy()` *probably* will be called, but it is not guaranteed.

Comment: I am new to using Service. Is it possible to call method at Service if I create service by 'startService'. I know method at Service can be called if I create service by 'bindService'.

Comment: @Android Beginner: You can send commands to services via `startService()`, where you package the work to be done via extras in the `Intent`. The service will receive that in `onStartCommand()` and can arrange to do the work. Bear in mind that `onStartCommand()`, like the vast majority of Android callbacks into your code, is called on the main application thread, so you need to either do little work or arrange for more work to be done on a background thread.

Comment: @Android Beginner: "can I call a method in Service after I called startService() (Just like create service by bindService())?" -- no. "Because user can add geo zone any time after the service started." -- send a fresh command via `startService()`. Go read the documentation on services. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html

Comment: Thanks, but can I call a method in Service after I called startService() (Just like create service by bindService())? Because user can add geo zone any time after the service started. I have a solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462037/register-receiver-in-a-service. Is it a good idea to register a broadcast receiver in Service?