# How to make the Intent live in the background

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

Well this question may seem vague ,as `Intent` pretty much live in the background.I agree with it,but I am using `Intent` filter programatically .I am putting two buttons,register and unregister. When pressed register, `Intent` filter is registered works same for unregister as well. Now when I press the register button and put the app in the background , the toast message won't get displayed. But I want the `Intent` filter to stop receiving the messages only when the user explicitly presses the unregister button.

**I am using this code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

 private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    // Get the object of SmsManager
        final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
            final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

            try {

                if (bundle != null) {

                    final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                    for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                        SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                        String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                        String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                        String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                        Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);


                       // Show alert
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                        toast.show();







                    } // end for loop
                  } // bundle is null

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

            }




        }

    };



public void register(View view){

    this.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));

}
public void unRegister(View view){

    this.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);


}



}
```

Comment: seems fair .. i have to check it ..thanks @MikeM.

Comment: @MikeM: implemented in your way .. no problem .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [BroadcastReceiver documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), a broadcast receiver which is programatically registered via an `Activity.registerReceiver()` won't receive any broadcast when the activity is not running:

> If registering a receiver in your Activity.onResume() implementation, you should unregister it in Activity.onPause(). (You won't receive intents when paused, and this will cut down on unnecessary system overhead)

You may consider using a background `Service` and register your broadcast receiver on it (see [register receiver in a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462037/register-receiver-in-a-service)).

Or, as @doctoror-drive pointed out, you can statically register your receiver in the manifest file and enable/disable it programmatically with `PackageManager`.

Comment: Wrong. You don't need any service. Instead, one must register a static receiver in Manifest.

Comment: @DoctororDrive: the thing is i'm avoiding static

Comment: @VamsiPavanMahesh you're avoiding static what?

Comment: static receiver ..cuz it will invoke the app always

Comment: @VamsiPavanMahesh if you need a receiver to invoke your app it needs to be static. If you need the static receiver only for certain period, you can unregister it http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html#broadcastreceiver_packagemanager