# open android activity in new task without using android:launchMode="singleTask"

Tags: android, android-intent

I've created a browser application with main activity which response to the following intents:

```
 <intent-filter> 
       <data android:scheme="http"/>
       <data android:scheme="https"/>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

On url click from other task (gmail, sms) if i choose my application, the activity is open in the same task as the calling task.
When I choose different browser (Mozila firefox, chrome, dolphine) they are opening in different task.

Looking on other browsers manifest, I see that no one using **android:launchMode="singleTask"**.

I don't want to use single task flag since it is not recommended by google and also makes me other prolems.

I tried to understand how does other browsers do it but didn't figure it out.

any ideas? is there other way to open my activity in different task without using singleTask flag?

Comment: maybe you can set a flag on the intent launching the activity:
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or 
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
check out the documentation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: no, since the applications that send the activity are not mine (gmail for example)

Comment: @user3398598, the suggestion from Guy makes sense: you should combine it with the answer from Emanuel - see my comment there. I understand you have already implemented a workaround, but this approach is more simple imho, just for a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to "bend the rules" a little, and you're not clear enough on what you're trying to avoid by not using `android:launchMode="singleTask"`.

So I would suggest researching into either:

1. Creating a `Service` and having that `Service` listen to the intent filter. Then having this `Service` open your `Activity`, and having the `Activity`'s affinity set correctly to match the `Service`'s. This would allow you to get over the issue where affinity is not binding the `Activity` correctly.
2. Having a silent `Activity` starting a new `Activity` and quiting. The silent `Activity` would start in a new stack (not in a singletask mode), and would shut itself down upon starting the `Activity` you actually need.

Comment: How service could listen the intent filter? It is possible only with activities

Comment: The simplest way is using an IntentService - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html.
The boilerplate way is using a BroadcastReceiver - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462037/register-receiver-in-a-service.

Answer (score 2):

You can check in onCreate if the activity is running in a single task. If not just finish() it and create it again with using FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

This may help you

```
   ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    for (RunningTaskInfo task : tasks) {
        if (ctx.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase(task.baseActivity.getPackageName())) 
          // check if it's the only one activity or whatever                               
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, getRunningTasks is only intended for debugging please see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int)

Comment: This is the best way, but it should be simplified: there is no need to check running tasks. It's sufficient to check `getData()` in `onCreate` method and if it's not null, restart new instance of the activity with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` passing `Uri` to it via custom extra, and then `finish()` current instance. I'm sure this is how other browsers work

Answer (score 2):

I have found the following description on Android Developers [site](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#TaskLaunchModes):

> As another example, the Android Browser application declares that the
>   web browser activity should always open in its own task—by specifying
>   the singleTask launch mode in the  element. This means that
>   if your application issues an intent to open the Android Browser, its
>   activity is not placed in the same task as your application. Instead,
>   either a new task starts for the Browser or, if the Browser already
>   has a task running in the background, that task is brought forward to
>   handle the new intent.

As you can see `android:launchMode=singleTask` is the right choice in your case. You already mentioned that you had issues with this property so maybe let's focus on them.

**Update 28.05.2014**

Note from Google regarding singleTask launchMode:

> The other modes — singleTask and singleInstance — are not appropriate
>   for most applications, since they result in an interaction model that
>   is likely to be unfamiliar to users and is very different from most
>   other applications.

singleTask and singleInstance use case from Google:

> Specialized launches (not recommended for general use)

As you can see singleTask may not be recommended for general use but your case is not general, actually it's one of the cases where singleTask fits perfectly.
In other words, singleTask is not forbidden, it's just need to be used with caution in order to provide end users common experience with your app.

I hope I made it clear now for you. Feel comfortable with this launch mode in your case.

Comment: I've tried it (put my package ID as the Affinity) but it is not working.  I think because my task was not started yet, so the activity will open in the calling task.

Comment: It should be opened in new task even if your activity was not started. Can you tell how do you determine that your activity is in the same task?

Comment: Two indications: FIRST: in task manager I see only one task (the messaging task) and when clicking on it i see my activity. SECOND: running "adb shell dumpsys activity" in "Running Activities" i see one task with two activities: mms and my activity.

Comment: I've put my package name as the Affinity, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it's fine. Did you remember to set allowTaskReparenting along with affinity? Can you also explain  why do you need your activity to be in the separate task? Maybe we could come up with another solution for the initial reason.

Comment: yes, I set allowTaskReparenting flag. as I wrote in the original question, I want my application act like other browsers, but looking in other browsers manifest it seems that no one is setting android:launchMode="singleTask".

Comment: Hi Loop, do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Why don't you describe what is your problem with singleTask? As I mentioned, singleTask is used by Google to do what you need. I don't see other option. Besides, singleTask is not recommended for general use. However, it does not apply to your case so you can use it without any worries. Once again, write about your issue with singleTask.

Comment: OK, thanks.  But there is still an open question: how all other browsers open in a new task without defining this mode?

Comment: I don't see a point to guess. Maybe they do some workarounds. Can you provide example and show manifest of this example? Anyway, you know what Google do with Android Browser. Is it not the best example to follow? I would say it is. I think this topic can be closed unless you provide info about your issue with singleTask, if there is any.