# Prevent Deeplink from being opened within the browser of the originating app

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking, branch.io

I am using [Branch.io](https://branch.io/) to Deeplink from the Salesforce App to my Cordova app. However, when I click the deeplink in the Salesforce app, it just opens my app within a browser inside the Salesforce app instead of actually taking me to my app. It seems like I should be using a `<intent-filter/>` to make that happen but it doesn't seem to be able to take me out of the originating Salesforce app. Here is what my `<intent-filter/>` currently is:

```
 <intent-filter android:name="io.branch.sdk.UriScheme">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="myapp" />
 </intent-filter>
 <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" android:name="io.branch.sdk.AppLink">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:host="myapp.app.link" android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

What other intent actions or categories do I need there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What actually definitively resolved this was going into the `AndroidManifest.xml` and setting `android:launchMode="singleTask"` on my main activity.

I know that  [in the android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#lmode) it says singleTask is not recommended. I believe that's because it prevents you from going back but we take over the functionality of the hardware back button so that's not relevant. Also according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23866656/2079907), it seems like the right thing to do in our context.

Answer (score 1):

You should only need the intent filters listed here:

- https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/#configure-app

If it is opening your app within the Salesforce browser, then it may be that Salesforce is preventing users from deep linking out of it.

Comment: Ok, I checked the Salesforce app in the Settings app and found there was a setting to open linked within the salesforce app of in the other app.