# How can i use Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: android

I want to receive notification when the messages arrives with using Broadcast Receiver. I wrote this code but it doesnt work;

I added this code in my AndroidManifest class;

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.SMSReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And my SMSReceiver class;

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle pudsBundle = intent.getExtras();
    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) pudsBundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage messages = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);
    Toast.makeText(context, "New SMS: " + messages.getMessageBody(),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(getClass().getName().toString(), "SMS Arrived");
    }

}
```

This code must show me a Toast Message when SMS arrived. How can i fix this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: You need to register the broadcast receiver in the activity or service that is supposed to catch the event, I believe, and you also need a permission: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462037/register-receiver-in-a-service

Answer (score 0):

You must have the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

If you want to send sms you will need permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to register your broadcast receiver. Hope for help.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
   super.onResume();

   // Register mMessageReceiver to receive messages.
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
    new IntentFilter("my-event"));
}
```