# Register a broadcast receiver in a Service

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I have an Activity, this Activity will call a Service and that Service will call a broadcast to listen for SMS coming. I register a broadcast in the Service dynamically.
But it's not working. My code is below. Please help me resolve. 
This is the `onCreate` method in the Service.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");

    this.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            showSuccessfulBroadcast();

        }
    }, filter);
}
```

Comment: check link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462037/register-receiver-in-a-service

Comment: Post the code for `onStartCommand()` in your Service. Is your Service an `IntentService`?

Comment: Define "not working". Maybe you mean that your receiver method didn't get called when an SMS arrived?

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct. Don't forget to declare used permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`, and to unregister receiver in `onDestroy()`. Both points are important.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

Inside your Service

```
private BroadcastReceiver mSmsBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        showSuccessfulBroadcast();
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");

    this.registerReceiver(mSmsBroadcastReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    this.unregisterReceiver(mSmsBroadcastReceiver);
}
```

Comment: Not needed for dynamically registered broadcast receivers.